# Flashing an LED while Raspberry Pi boots, then illuminate constantly via GPIO

Tags: led, raspberry-pi, 555

I would like to flash an LED when my 5V power supply is turned on to indicate my Raspberry Pi is booting. Then, when booted and my application is running, I'd like to make a GPIO high (or low) and have the same LED constantly illuminated. This would indicate the system is ready for us.

The Raspberry Pi will be in a case and the would be no other way for a user to determine it is ready to use.

So far, I've made a simple 555 circuit to flash the LED  but can not work out where I can add a transistor to be controlled by GPIO to either bypass the 555 or change the R1 or C1 values so the flash rate is 1kHz or more and so imperceivable.

Is there a simple addition I can make to the circuit below to achieve this?

[image: 555 timer schematic]

Comment: Having a LED that blink while booting is giving mostly false reassurance to a user. I suggest a full-on LED while booting, turning off at end of boot, blinking when the thing is active. Much more truthful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NE555 has a reset pin. You can control it with GPIO.

Comment: I think I can see how I could use the reset pin to turn the LED off via GPIO, but is it possible to turn the LED on using it too?

Comment: @edlea Connect the LED so that it is permanently lit when NE555 is in reset.

Comment: I.e. connect the anode to your supply voltage through an appropriate resistor and the cathode to OUTPUT so it *sinks* the LED current (LED lit when OUTPUT is low) rather than sources it.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the circuit built and can't change it, this might work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4zOhx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Driving a LED with no resistor is never a good option.

Comment: @Justme Yeah. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a flashing LED as a simple flash circuit and bypass it with the GPIO after startup.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXN6iJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>